# Getting information from database then update in the same block of code (Proper syntax)

Tags: java, mysql, swing, netbeans

Im trying to get "fees" from the database and use it to calculate the new "fee" based on the deposit the user enters and update the database with this new "fee"

```
 private void PfeeBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:



    double fee;

    double inp;
    Connection conn=null;

    try{
      Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
     conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/students", "root","Splash7727#" );
     String sql= ("select  fees  from students.studentinfo where studentId = ?");
      PreparedStatement  pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      Integer id=Integer.parseInt(stuIdTxt.getText());
      pst.setInt(1,id);

      ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
      if (rs.next())
      {
          fee=rs.getInt(1);
          inp=Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Deposit amount"));
         double nfee=fee-inp;



          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "New balance is:$"+nfee);

          String sql2 =("update studentinfo set fees =? where studentId ='"+id+"'");
          PreparedStatement  pst2=conn.prepareStatement(sql2);


          pst.setDouble(1,nfee );
          pst2.executeUpdate();
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record updated");

      }

          else
      {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record not found");
      }


      }catch (Exception e)
              {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }

}
```

Error Message that I am getting. I dont know why if you can explain to me what I am doing wrong that would be great thank you.I dont know if its the syntax or this code is just plain wrong. I am a beginner so ya

```
 java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1115)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdateInternal(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1040)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1347)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1025)
at wecare.Fee.PfeeBtnActionPerformed(Fee.java:191)
at wecare.Fee.access$100(Fee.java:20)
at wecare.Fee$2.actionPerformed(Fee.java:67)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2348)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6535)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6300)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2236)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4891)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2294)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4888)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4525)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4466)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2280)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2750)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4713)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:758)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:729)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:728)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all:

```
String sql2 =("update studentinfo set fees =? where studentId ='"+id+"'");
```

One of the reasons for using a PreparedStatement is to make the code easy read and maintain and prevent SQL syntax errors by using parameters. You already used a parameter in your first SQL statement, so why did you change in this statement?

Your SQL should be:

```
String sql2 =("update studentinfo set fees = ? where studentId = ?);
```

Much easier to read, maintain and understand without all the "'+..+"'" etc.

Then you set the parameters of the statement the same way you did before.

```
pst.setDouble(1, nfee );
pst.setInt(2, id);
```

Won't fix your problem, but know you have more consistent readable code.

> java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 1

So that is telling you that a parameter to one of you SQL statement is invalid. So which statement is causing the problem? Well, the stack trace will tell you. You look for a statement that is part of your code:

```
at wecare.Fee.PfeeBtnActionPerformed(Fee.java:191)
```

Now that you know the statement were the problem is you can display the value of your variables that you use. For example:

```
System.out.println(id);
System.out.println(…);
```

I'm guessing the variable does not contain what you expect, so figure out why and then fix the problem.
This is basic debugging you do before asking a question. Then if you don't know how to solve the problem, you tell use the statement that is causing the problem and maybe we can suggest a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution, it probably doesn't meet the standards but it works and I only got a couple of hours left to submit this. Thank you for trying to help me.

```
private void PfeeBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        
    // TODO add your handling code here:



    double fee;
    double nfee;
    double inp;
    Connection conn=null;

    try{
      Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
     conn=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/students", "root","Splash7727#" );
     String sql= ("select  fees  from students.studentinfo where studentId = ?");
      PreparedStatement  pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
      Integer id=Integer.parseInt(stuIdTxt.getText());
      pst.setInt(1,id);

      ResultSet rs=pst.executeQuery();
      if (rs.next())
      {
          fee=rs.getInt(1);
          inp=Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Enter Deposit amount"));
          nfee=fee-inp;



          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "New balance is:$"+nfee);



      String sql2 =("update studentinfo set fees =? where studentId ='"+id+"'");
      PreparedStatement  pst2=conn.prepareStatement(sql2);







          pst2.setDouble(1,nfee );
          pst2.executeUpdate();
           JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record updated");


      }

          else
      {
          JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record not found");
      }

            conn.close();
      }catch (Exception e)
              {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }



}
```

Comment: How is this a solution?. We have no idea what has changed here from the original code you posted. The point of  posting and answer is to explain what was wrong and to give details about the solution. You still haven't fixed your second SQL statement.